# Alsa pause and resume

Tags: linux, resume, alsa

I am trying to pause and un-pause the alsa audio. Calling the `pcm_pause(alsaHandle,0)` pauses the audio immediately but un-pausing it using `snd_pcm_pause(alsaHandle,1)` does not start the audio play until `snd_pcm_drain(alsaHandle)` is called. But `snd_pcm_drain()` does not return until all of the audio in the buffer has been played. So, I cannot pause the audio again if I need to. I would like to know if there is a way to pause/un-pause audio freely.

Comment: Dare I ask why you didn't implement it at the application level?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, I eventually had to do so. But I was wondering why such a basic functionality is not provided by default by alsa.

Comment: Because it's not the audio layer's job to control the app.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But it is providing immediate pause functionality, then why not immediate resume?

Comment: I don't know. But it's not the audio layer's job regardless.